# C Unix semaphores: process should wait for 0, but doesn't

Tags: c, unix, semaphore, ipcs

have written two simple functions, one for setting a semaphore to an arbitrary value (Reset) and another one to make the process calling it wait for the semaphore to be zero:

```
int R(int semid, int semnum, int val)   // reset
{
    union semun arg;
    arg.val = val;
    if( semctl(sem_id,semnum,SETVAL,arg) == -1 )  
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Errore inizializzazione del semaforo\n%s\n",
                strerror(errno) );
    }
}

int Z(int semid, int semnum)    // wait for zero
{
        printf("waiting for zero on %d\n",semid);
        struct sembuf cmd;
        cmd.sem_num = semnum;
        cmd.sem_op = 0;
        cmd.sem_flg = 0;
        if(semop(semid, &cmd, 1)<0) {ERROR}
        return 0;
}
```

The process that is using those functions as a code that looks like this:

```
while(1) {
    R(sem_id_counter,0,N_PROC_DEFAULT);  // (N_PROC_DEFAULT=5)

    /* list of tasks not having anything to do with sem_id_coutner */

    Z(sem_id_counter,0);
}
```

What happens is that the above process just keeps executing the loop, while I want it to stop at the end, when it calls the function Z, waiting for the semaphore to become 0 before resetting it to its initial content and restart.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks   [ solved: stupid typo sem_id instead of semid ]

Comment: What's the value of N_PROC_DEFAULT?

Comment: You need two threads, one that resets the semaphore and the other that sets it.

Comment: You also need to check `semop` return value, there are no exceptions in C.

Comment: N_PROC_DEFAULT = 5 and the process that actually sets the semaphore is a different one (although I don't see why Code Monkey says it couldn't be the same one)

Comment: Maxim. you're right, I've added the check, but it is not semop to fail

Comment: Show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please.  Your function `R()` takes an argument of `semid` but operates on `sem_id` \[sic\].  Right now we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: you're right pilcrow thanks so much I did not notice that.